# After reading image, it cannot count pixels with specific values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My program is reading an image 256x256, which is labeled by three values (0,1,2). My program should count the number of pixels for each label.However,whenever I run the program it is not counting label `1 and 2`.

```
 from __future__ import division
import caffe
import numpy as np 
from scipy.misc import imread
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter

sample_img_path='/path/to/image/label-002-014.png'
    im=imread(sample_img_path)

    print im.shape

    cl0=np.count_nonzero(im == 0)   #0=background class
    cl1=np.count_nonzero(im == 1)   #1=obj1,   
    cl2=np.count_nonzero(im == 2)   #2=obj2,

    print cl0,cl1,cl2
```

output

```
(256, 256)
64313 0 0
```

Could you please guide me with this? how to solve?

Comment: I think you need a more complete listing. `imread` does not appear to be part of the stock python distro, so your listing should include your `imports` so people know what other modules you are working with. Also, it's not clear what `np` is. It just shows up in the middle of your listing with no hint of what type it actually is.

Comment: @TravisGriggs thanks for your recommendation, I updated the question

Comment: Does 1223 pixels (the number unaccounted for in your totals) sound about right for the total of obj1 and obj2?  Perhaps they just ended up with different pixel values than `1` and `2` due to the .png file's palette getting reordered somehow.